# SQL LEFT_JOIN table on itself while replacing column

Tags: sql, replace, null, azure-sql-database, left-join

I have the following data:

```
value1    value2    value3
qwe       bird      1
qwe                 2
qwe                 3
asd       dog       4
asd                 5
```

And I would like the following data:

```
value1    value2    value3
qwe       bird      1
qwe       bird      2
qwe       bird      3
asd       dog       4
asd       dog       5
```

To me it seems like the problem that can be fixed by left joining two columns of the table on itself, while replacing a column. Something like:

```
# Selecting unique value1 and value2 combinations
SELECT value1, value2
FROM mytable
WHERE value2 != ''
GROUP BY value1, value2

# Left joining two tables
SELECT value1, value2
FROM selection_table
LEFT JOIN mytable
ON selection_table.value1 = mytable.value1;
```

Can I somehow make this entire operation in one call, such that I avoid having to make intermediate tables? When doing my left join, can I overwrite the value2 column?

Or do you have a more intelligent way to do this? I am sure there must be one :)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Is there only a single value2 for each value1?

Comment: Yes, only a single value2 for each value1. In some cases I might run into there being a duplications of the pair though.

Comment: And you want all three columns or just multiple rows with the same value1 & value2?

Comment: Yes, correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution applies a *Windowed Aggregate*

```
SELECT value1
  ,max(value2) -- group maximum
   over (partition by value1)
  ,value3
from mytable
```

This is usually more efficient than a solution based on a self-join.

Comment: Seems to work :) Final question - if I want to overwrite the "mytable" with the results, and I want to include extra columns like value4, value5..... without having to write them explicitly, can I also do that?

Comment: What do you mean by *overwrite*? Update the table? This would be a simple UPDATE FROM using `SELECT value1
  ,max(value2) , 'bla' as value4, 0 as value5
from mytable group by 1` or a similar MERGE

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I am not from SQLverse, but have 8+ years experience in R and Python, where tables function quite a bit differently :)

Answer (score 1):

In standard SQL, you can use `lag(ignore nulls)`:

```
select t.*, lag(value2 ignore nulls) over (partition by value1 order by value3) 
from t;
```

However, many databases do not implement this functionality.  One method is two levels of aggregation, one to get the `value3` with a value and second to spread the value:

```
select t.*,
       max(value2) over (partition by value1, grp)
from (select t.*,
             max(case when value2 is not null then value3 end) over (partition by value1 order by value3) as grp
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I am slightly confused by the syntax. What does "max(value2)" do? Also why mess with value 3? It is just to show that the data has more columns, nothing should be done to that. I am trying to make your queries work on Azure SQL right now. If I get it working I will of cause accept your answer :)